# Connection between two IVPs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have two IVPs:$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{k}y'+y &= 0, ~~~y(0)=5\\\\\frac{1}{k}y'+y&=5,~~~y(0)=0\end{align}$$
The solutions are:
$$\begin{align}y(t) &= 5e^{-kt}\\y(t)&=5-5e^{-kt}\end{align}$$ 
[image]

Everywhere, both graphs are adding up nicely to $5$ and this is the case for *every* initil value/input. I don't think this is a coincidence but I can't see past the algebra. I feel this has to do with some symmetry or interesting physical phenomena. Any help?

---

Comment: Your second function is not a solution of that differential equation unless $k=1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Oh right! I know how to fix... must scale the input by $k$. I'll update it quick. Thanks:)

Comment: @pooja, If interested you can try out this group. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76340/jee-maths-zone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two equations can be rewritten as 
\begin{align}
y'=k(0-y), & \quad y(0)=5\\
y'=k(5-y), & \quad y(0)=0,
\end{align}

Which means that the first equation starts at 5 and always moves toward 0, and the second equation does the opposite. For sensible and equal choices of $k$ in each equation, they have to be mirror images of each other.

Comment: Hey you could tell that that first solution always moves toward $0$ just by looking at the differential equation?

Comment: Hmm since $k\gt 0$ we have $y'=-ky\lt 0$... so $y$ is decreasing. Is this your reasoning?

Comment: Because y' is always negative number, since y starts at 5, and 0-5k is negative whenever k is positive.

Comment: Gotcha. Beautiful!

Comment: If I get this correctly, the second solution is always increasing because $y'=5k-ky = k(5-y) \gt 0$ for $0\lt y\lt 5$. But I don't get why it cannot go beyond $5$..

Comment: That's because $y'$ remains positive but gets very small as $yk$ approaches 5. Actually the symmetry would be ruined if $k\neq 1$.

Comment: symmetry is fine https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jlyz4fl9ib ?

Comment: Ahh $y'\to 0$ as $y\to 5$and $y\to 5$. don't see how $k\ne 1$ ruins symmetry though.. it looks fine on the graph

Comment: You're absolutely right. $k$ just changes the rate of convergence to the asymptote, I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the quantity $z=x+y$, where $x$ solves the first IVP and $y$ solves the second. Then $z$ solves the IVP $$\frac{1}{k}z'=5-z, \ \ \ z(0) = 5.$$ At $t=0$, $z=5$, so $z'(0) = 5-5=0$, so $z$ is constant for all $t$.

Comment: Clever! If I understand you cooked up that new IVP by adding the given two IVPs. I get till $z'(0)=0$. But $z'$ may not be $0$ for *other* $t$ right? How did you conclude $z$ is constant *for all t* ?

Comment: Consider a new quantity $w = x+y-5$. Then $w'=0$ and $w(0)=0$. We can solve this explicitly to obtain that $w=0$ for all $t$, so $z=5$ for all $t$

Comment: I see $z=5$ is actually an integral curve; so once an IVP starts there, it stays there forever. You're awesome:)

Comment: I maybe wrong but it seems if an IVP starts with $0$ slope, it stays at the initial value forever.

Comment: For an IVP with constant coefficients and constant inhomogeneous term, yes.